# Direct Initialization vs Copy Initialization for Primitives

Tags: c++, initialization, variable-assignment, primitive

When initializing primitive types like `int` or pointers one can use either *copy-initialization* or *direct-initialization*.

```
int a = 10;
int b(10);
```

Although the latter way is preffered for objects with constructors, I don't see people using it for primitives. I understand that it is kind of "more natural" (especially for numbers) to use the '=' operator but is there anybody writing things like in real-life code:

```
for (int i(0); i < 5; ++i) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Thanks.

EDIT: The question asks about coding styles and best practices rather than technical implementation.

Comment: "Do you ever write code like this?" isn't really a suitable question for SO...

Comment: I've seen code like this and I don't like it. I even initialize class-type variables using the copy initialization syntax if possible. Copy elisions FTW.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I am asking for best practices and recommended styles.

Comment: Subjective and broad questions like this are not for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people do this to be consistent.

Inside a template, the code could be

```
for (T i(0); i < 5; ++i) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

and writing it that way everywhere would make the coding style consistent.

Comment: Why couldn't it be written the other way around inside a template?

Comment: This saves type T from having an assignment operator taking a `0`. It is enough to have a constructor.

Comment: To have a constructor taking a `0`, right? So it would work if writing  `i = 0` anyway.

Comment: Not if the constructor is explicit. The idea is to minimize the requirements on the type T, so the code works in as many cases as possible.

Comment: In this case you require that type T behaves almost like an `int`, so it implements a constructor taking an `int`, the `operator<` and the prefix `operator++`. It's just a non-sense that type T provides all these and not the assignment operator for `int`. IMHO it is not worth to spread a harder to read code style through your codebase just for this reason.

Comment: The style would mostly be used in template libraries where you want the code to work with as many types as possible. There you wouldn't have `< 5` but `!= end_condition`. The minimal requirements for a type would then be having a constructor (implicit or explicit), `operator!=`, and `operator++`.

Comment: @BoPersson let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2652/discussion-between-antonio-perez-and-bo-persson)

Answer (score 3):

Both are initialization using the copy constructor, even though the first looks like an assignment. It's just syntactic sugar.

You could check it easily with a class that prints out something at copy construction and something different at assignment.

And int being a primitive doesn't even come into play.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a colleague doing so:

```
for (int i(0); i < 5; ++i) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

and it really pissed everyone off. It's far easier to read the code using `i = 0` than `i(0)`. Maybe not in this example but, as a general rule, it is.

Even for complex objects, I always prefer the `i = 0` style, it just feels more natural for the reader and any decent compiler will optimize the generated code so there is virtually no performance penalty.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the `i = 0` style, it is easier to read, and you can also use it in like this:

```
if (int i = some_function())
{
}
```

Works also fine with pointers, and all other types convertible to bool:

```
if (const int* p = some_function())
{
}

if (shared_ptr<const int> q = some_function())
{
}
```